# How to check my crontab listed files running every minute or not?

Tags: cron

---

The following code represents the crontab for every files.

```
* * * * * /proj/dev/r_new_1/1.5/n1_rb.pl

* * * * * /proj/dev/r_new_1/1.5/bin/n1_rb.cgi
```

i want to check whether the above crontab running every minute or not

Comment: check the logfiles under `/var/log`

Comment: You application should also do some logging / allow some logging/debugging.

Answer (score 0):

To find out where cron logs to you can use grep:

```
grep CRON /var/log/*
```

To view your log in real time use tail with the follow flag:

```
tail -f /var/log/LOGFILE
```

Comment: Standart in Debian cron loggs to /var/log/syslog